# Flutter cannot call async function from another class

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I am trying to create a simple wrapper for the rest client by facing following issue:

I have an external class:

```
typedef void Callback(int code, String body);

class HttpClient {
void post(String url, Map<String, String> headers, Map<String, String> params,
   Callback callback) async {
 final encoding = Encoding.getByName('utf-8');

   Response response =
     await post(url, headers: headers, body: params, encoding: encoding);
   callback(200, "lol");
 }
}
```

My `await post(...)` is highlighted and says the following error: "The expression here has a type of 'void', and therefore can't be used.

Interesting, that if I change my method to private the highlighting disappears.

I can  also declare `post` as a private function and then call it from another public fuction passing all the same params and it works.

How should I write this function and then call it another place? Thanks!

**EDIT**

Thanks for @Jack I could find the solution:

import should be

```
 import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

And 
     Response response =
     await post(url, headers: headers, body: params, encoding: encoding);

Should be changed to

```
 var response =
    await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: params, encoding: encoding);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IDE thinks you are referencing your `post` method instead of `http.post` as your method returns a void. This can be solved by replacing: `await post(...)` with `await http.post(...)`. Hope this help! If this doesn't work please leave a comment below.

Comment: @Igor Skryl , if this solved your problem, please accept as an answer. Thanks :)

Comment: thanks for the answer! It says "undefined name 'http'"

Comment: I am just little bit confused, because when I used the same method in the `State` with the same imports it worked

Comment: Ok, your post helped, but more explanations should be added